# What is the meaning of & placed at the end of a declaration?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

First of all, thank you for your time and consideration!
I am a fortran user and quite new with c++, and I need your help to understand some bit of coding that was passed on to me. I am pasting a small part of the code that bothers me most.

```
tmp<volScalarField> talpha = thermo.alpha();
const volScalarField& alpha = talpha();
tmp<volScalarField> tkappa = thermo.kappa();
const volScalarField& kappa = tkappa();

volScalarField& h = thermo.he();

const volScalarField& betav = betavSolid[i];

fv::IOoptionList& fvOptions = solidHeatSources[i];
```

My main concern is with the '&' placed at the end of declarations, what does it mean ? Also, why create a tmp field talpha for instance and declare next alpha=talpha ? Why not allocating thermo.alpha() to alpha directly ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not intended to teach you basic C++ syntax.

Comment: For learning basics such as this, reading a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) is vastly superior to asking piecewise questions on SO.

Comment: @skyking ??? It's actually marked as dupe?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Wasn't on my monitor!??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ For some wierd reason it wasn't (on my monitor at least) at the time I commented. The "probably dupe" comment had been removed though.

Comment: _"why create a tmp field `talpha` for instance and declare next `alpha=talpha`"_ Where does the code say that? Hint: it _doesn't_. It says `alpha=talpha()`. **Reading** is a crucial skill when you're programming; I suggest giving it a go. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a reference type.

C++ has three basic types: values, pointers and references. Reference type is similar to pointer, with two exceptions:

- reference has to be initialized when created (via assign operation on a value or another reference),
- reference cannot be changed to refer to another variable (similarly to "const pointer"),
- references use "dot" operator like values for struct and classes fields instead of "arrow" as it is with pointers.

Comment: There are some misleading statements here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: would you care to elaborate?